# Convert utm to lat long in csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, utm

```
import pandas
import utm
df = pd.read_csv("0006.csv")
```

this is the output of the imported csv file

```
       Description     PositionDateTime          X           Y       Z  \
0           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:00:08  668471.51  7473216.92   43.60   
1           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:00:09  668471.51  7473216.90   43.62   
2           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:00:39  668471.63  7473216.49   44.00   
3           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:01:02  668471.66  7473216.41   44.07   
4           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:01:14  668471.66  7473216.39   44.09   
5           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:01:48  668471.67  7473216.37   44.11   
6           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:01:54  668471.67  7473216.37   44.11   
7           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:02:36  668471.67  7473216.37   44.11   
8           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:02:39  668471.67  7473216.37   44.11   
9           DT0006  2018-01-01 00:03:18  668451.81  7473220.04   52.36
```

Assuming the Zone is 45K, I would like to use utm to convert X, Y into latitude and longitude.
So far I know how to convert like this

```
utm.to_latlon(???, ???, ??, '?')
```

How do I convert each numbers of lat and long into separate columns?

What I did was this

```
df['lat'], df['long'] = utm.to_latlon(df.X, df.Y, 45, 'K')
```

This is wrong, still looking how to do that.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **[`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)** and **[`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

```
def rule(row):
    lat, lon = utm.to_latlon(row["X"], row["Y"], 45, 'K')
    return pd.Series({"lat": lat, "long": long})
df.merge(df.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Appreciate it

Comment: I just typed df but the data which are merged and applied didn't show the converted datasets. How to apply those before I export csv?

Comment: you have to reassign it, i.e. `df = df.merge(df.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)`